# Put a city point on svg map in js

Tags: javascript, svg

I just try to put a point of a city on a `svg map` in `javascript`.

#### Explaination:

What I have:

French Map (128x128px) in svg:

[image: French map]

Coords in WGS84 like:

[image: Coords of city]

I want to put a point of the city paris.
I search on this website and I found this code but nothing is explain so I don't know what is `mapLonLeft`, `mapLatBottom` and `mapLatBottomDegree`.

```
function convertGeoToPixel(latitude, longitude ,
                       mapWidth , // in pixels
                       mapHeight , // in pixels
                       mapLonLeft , // in degrees
                       mapLonDelta , // in degrees (mapLonRight - mapLonLeft);
                       mapLatBottom , // in degrees
                       mapLatBottomDegree) // in Radians
{
    var x = (longitude - mapLonLeft) * (mapWidth / mapLonDelta);

    latitude = latitude * Math.PI / 180;
    var worldMapWidth = ((mapWidth / mapLonDelta) * 360) / (2 * Math.PI);
    var mapOffsetY = (worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(mapLatBottomDegree)) / (1 - Math.sin(mapLatBottomDegree))));
    var y = mapHeight - ((worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(latitude)) / (1 - Math.sin(latitude)))) - mapOffsetY);

    return { "x": x , "y": y};
}
```

Comment: That's not an svg

Comment: At base it an svg but the image hoster convert it ;)

Comment: Why not leave it as an SVG then so we can test the functions in our answers?

Answer (score 0):

Here are what each of `convertGeoToPixel`'s arguments mean:

- `latitude` - the latitude of the point you want to draw on the map.
- `longitude` - the longitude of the point you want to draw on the map.
- `mapWidth` - the map's width in pixels
- `mapHeight` - the map's height in pixels
- `mapLonLeft` - the real-world longitude of the left-most side of the map
- `mapLonDelta` - the "width" of the map in degrees of longitude
- `mapLatBottom` - the latitude (real-world) of the bottom of the map
- `mapLatBottomDegree` - `mapLatBottom` converted to radians

So, looking at your map:

[image: france]

You'd have to check the longitude of its left-hand side, the longitude of its right-hand side and the latitude of its bottom side.

[image: france]

It looks as if you can be fairly accurate setting these values:

```
latitude = 48.8667
longitude = 2.33333
mapWidth = mapHeight = 128
mapLonLeft = -5
mapLonDelta = 14
mapLatBottom = 42
mapLatBottomDegree = mapLatBottom * pi/180
```

These values are however *extremely* crude estimates, try to find the exact values of the lat/long of the edges of your map if you can.

Whether or not that function does as promised though is another matter...

Comment: "Whether or not that function does as promised though is another matter..." what that it means ?

Comment: @Jean-benoitRichez Well, I don't know if that function you've posted will actually work.